# Is it possible to use an Android phone as an input device for Windows over bluetooth?

Tags: windows-7, android, bluetooth

I have a htc hero and my windows 7 pc has a bluetooth dongle. Is there an app that will allow me to use my phone as a keyboard and/or mouse?

Comment: You could install a VNC-Server on the Windows-Machine and use a VNC Client on your mobile. It's far from beeing a perfect solution but it should work
http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-viewer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.gmote.org/). Gmote has a "touchpad" mode, which also lets you use it as a keyboard.

Comment: Nice, will have to try this one too.

Answer (score 0):

We have some people working on a app that will WORK, but till not there is actually not an app that works the way you want. ofc, there are allways ways, and new ways are added daily, but RIGHT NOW, there is nothing i would recommend.

Comment: Ofc you have VNC, but i did not get TO much out of it at work (want to use my Hero at work)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah totes. There's this really cool android (and iphone, i think) app. Let's you use your touchscreen phone as a mouse and also type with it too. It's called "[Remote Mouse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hungrybolo.remotemouseandroid)". I've tried it and it works very well. Very very minimal setup too. Just install server on your PC, install app on phone, hit connect!