# Can I use my Samsung Galaxy S5 as a trackpad?

Tags: macos, mac, touchpad

My wireless mouse needs to be recharged. My trackpad - too. Is it possible to use my Samsung Galaxy S5 as a trackpad, not wireless preferrably? (I plugged it in my Mac Mini).

Comment: Did you do any research on it?

Comment: @CharlieRB Yes, I did. Maybe I am bad at googling, as I have not found anything yet. Comment if you will find something.

Comment: There are several applications that do what you ask, but they all use wireless.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/465840/control-windows-8-with-a-tablet, http://superuser.com/questions/111953/is-it-possible-to-use-an-android-phone-as-an-input-device-for-windows-over-bluet?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/564421/how-would-you-turn-a-tablet-into-a-keyboard-easy-to-reach-touchscreen-mirror

Comment: @techie007 Unfortunatly, none of them.

Comment: None of them what?  Did you try any of the suggested answers? What were your results?

Comment: @techie007 None of them are dupes.

Comment: *Did you try any of the suggested answers? What were your results?*

Comment: @techie007 Of course they don't solve my problem (are you kidding eh?). If I solved it, I didn't start bounty.

Comment: Found these options at the android SE site. some of the apps say turns it into touchscreen/mouse for PC.  http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40934/use-an-android-tablet-as-a-wacom-drawing-tablet-for-a-pc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a program called Hippo Remote for my iPhone and it looks like they have the app available for Samsung phones too.  It works over wifi but I don't believe there is a plug and play feature but it may accomplish your goal.  Link can be found below.

After downloading you just need to add a connection and the connection should be a Hippo Connect.  You then will be asked to provide the name of the computer, IP address of the computer (on your network) and a password for security.

http://hipporemote.com/

Answer (score 1):

The only way you will be able to do this is with an app in the middle - this is not natively supported behavoiur.

The trackpads on samsung phones merely pass actions to the android os (click, drag, pinch et)  Unless you can find an "app-in-the-middle" to do this, its nor natively supported.

Also, since the S5 doesn't register as a HID (Human Interface Device) In windows, it would suggest further that this isn't possible natively.

That said, I have just spent a little time on various app stores.  HippoRemote, RemoteDroid and RemoteMouse all seem to be able to accomplish what you are after.

Answer (score -1):

Using SplashTop (www.splashtop.com) as a VNC server, you can 'view' your laptop screen from your phone and use the screen as a mouse.
It's a high network-overhead solution, but it does offer what you're looking for.